# Unix command(s) to find/replace in many files

Tags: unix

I'm trying to delete a string out of several files on a Rasberry Pie. My directory structure is the following:

```
./games/GAMESYSTEMONE/gamelist.xml  
./games/SOMEOTHERGAMESYSTEM/gamelist.xml  
./games/YETANOTHERGAMESYSTEM/gamelist.xml
```

and I want to delete every occurance of the string: `<favorite>true</favorite>`
from each of those gamelist.xml files. It can appear many times. I've been messing with grep and sed, but I can't seem to make the files change. I'd really appreciate some guidance here.

Answer (score 1):

From the ./games directory, run the following command:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed 's/<favorite>true<//favorite>//g' gamelist.xml
```

Comment: When I first entered this, I got:find: missing argument to '-exec', so I added \; to the end, and now it's saying sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Additionally, if I change my command to be: find ./ -type f -exec sed 's@<favorite>true</favorite>@@g' gamelist.xml \;, I get an error sed: can't read gamelist.xml: No such file or directory for all the files it's trying to execute sed for.

Comment: `find . -name gamelist.xml -type f -exec sed 's@<favorite>true</favorite>@@g' {} \;`